# Hacer clic en un enlace en una prueba de Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chrome

Estoy tratando de hacer que mi prueba de Selenium haga clic en el enlace game.html en la página userinyerface.com

```
<div class="view__row">
          <p>Please <u>click</u> <a class="start__link" href="/game.html">HERE</a> to GO to the <span class="start__highlight">next page</span></p>
        </div>
```

Cada vez que ejecuto el script, recibo la excepción siguiente:

no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"HERE"}

eL script de java es el siguiente:

```
@Test
    public void clickLinkToNextPage() throws Exception {
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("HERE")).click();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("HERE)")));
        driver.quit();
    }
```

Ya intenté mediante xpath, class name y link text, pero no lo logro.

Answer (score 0):

Hola Eduardo estuve haciendo unas pruebas y debes intentar llegar al nodo a, con el siguiente xpath: //p[contains(text(),'Please')]//a

Con ese xpath me funciono el click.

Te dejo un link con buena documentacion para que puedas aumentar tu nivel en deteccion de localizadores https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html

Saludos.